# Prove by Hilbert deduction: ⊢∃x(AvB)→(∃xAv∃xB); ⊢(∃xAv∃xB)→∃x(AvB)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory

I'd really like your help proving:

1)⊢∃x(AvB)→(∃xAv∃xB)

2)⊢(∃xAv∃xB)→∃x(AvB)

Our proof system contains next Hilbert's axioms:

1.A→(B→A)

2.(A→B)→((A→(B→X))→(A→X))

3.(A&B)→A

4.(A&B)→B

5.(A→B)→((A→X)→(A→(B&X)))

6.A→(AvB)

7.A→(BvA)

8.(A→X)→((B→X)→((AvB)→X))

9.(A→B)→((A→¬B)→¬A)

10.¬¬A→A

And other two axioms: ∀xA→A{t/x}, A{t/x}→∃xA where t is free for assignment instead of x in A.

Finally theres the MP rules:

1.From A,A→B we conclude B

2.From A→B we conclude A→∀xB, where x not included in the set of variables A free

3.From A→B we conclude ∃xA→B, where x not included in the set of variables A free

I tried couple of different ways but didn't come with any smart result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the **first** formula :

*a)* $A \rightarrow \exists x A$ --- 2nd Axiom for quantifiers

*b)* $\exists x A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B )$ --- from your 6)

*c)* $ [ \exists x A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) ] \rightarrow [ A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) ) ] $ --- from your 1)

*d)* $ A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) ) $ --- from b) and c) by MP

*e)* $ A \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) $ --- from a) and d) using your 2) by MP twice

In the same way, you can get :

*f)* $ B \rightarrow ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) $ --- using your 7)

*g)* $ ( A \lor B ) \rightarrow  ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) $ --- from e) and f) using your 8) by MP twice

Now you can get :

*h)* $ \exists x ( A \lor B ) \rightarrow  ( \exists x A \lor \exists x B ) $ --- from g) using your rule 3) ( because $x$ is not free in $( \exists x A \lor \exists x B )$ ).

Following a similar approach, you can try with the **second** formula.